# How can I identify orphaned site collection administrators with powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, check-permissions

I've noticed a number of sites where site collection administrator and users approving permissions have since been decommissioned in active directory. Is there a way I can identify all of these throughout the farm using powershell?

Extracting and providing a json list of users from Active Directory to then use against another script could be an option if somebody knows how to find this information within SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below is a PowerShell script to find inactive users. Please check if it works for you. Please note that code to delete the inactive users is at the bottom and is commented.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Parameter
$WebAppURL="https://sharepoint.crescent.com"


    #Function to Check if a User exists in AD
    Function Check-UserExistsInAD()
    {
        Param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$UserLoginID )

      #Search the User in AD
      $forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
      foreach ($Domain in $forest.Domains)
      {
            $context = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Domain", $Domain.Name)
            $domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($context)

            $root = $domain.GetDirectoryEntry()
            $search = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$root
            $search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$UserLoginID))"
            $result = $search.FindOne()

            if ($result -ne $null)
            {
               return $true
            }
      }
      return $false  
     }

    #Get all Site Collections of the web application
    $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

     #Iterate through all Site Collections
    Foreach($site in $WebApp.Sites) 
    {
            #Get all Webs with Unique Permissions - Which includes Root Webs
            $WebsColl = $site.AllWebs | Where {$_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True} | ForEach-Object {

            $OrphanedUsers = @()

           #Iterate through the users collection
           foreach($User in $_.SiteUsers)
           {
              #Exclude Built-in User Accounts , Security Groups
              if(($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\authenticated users") -and
                    ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "sharepoint\system") -and
                      ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\local service")  -and
                      ($user.IsDomainGroup -eq $false ) )
                   {
                       $UserName = $User.LoginName.split("\")  #Domain\UserName
                       $AccountName = $UserName[1]    #UserName
                        if ( ( Check-UserExistsInAD $AccountName) -eq $false )
                        {
                                   Write-Host "$($User.Name)($($User.LoginName)) from $($_.URL) doesn't Exists in AD!"

                                    #Make a note of the Orphaned user
                                    $OrphanedUsers+=$User.LoginName
                        }
                   }
}

# ****  Remove Users ****#
# Remove the Orphaned Users from the site
# foreach($OrpUser in $OrphanedUsers)
#   {
#        $_.SiteUsers.Remove($OrpUser)
#        Write-host "Removed the Orphaned user $($OrpUser) from $($_.URL) "
#   }
```

Reference - http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/find-and-delete-orphaned-users-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html