# Export and get the list of Orphaned users from SharePoint 2016 On premises - using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, powershell-script

I'm using SharePoint 2016 On-premises server, we have two main site collection, I need to get a list of orphaned users in each site collection.

I've come across this PowerShell script mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233925/how-can-i-identify-orphaned-site-collection-administrators-with-powershell)
which gives me a list of all users in my site collection, which is not meeting my requirement.

**I want to get the list of Orphaned users(who are not part of the active directory) from SharePoint 2016 On-prem - using PowerShell in an excel format or txt format,**

Please help me with some power-shell script

Comment: Please look at this - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252229/disabled-user-profile-not-deleted

Comment: HI @Raf, thanks for sharing the link, i want a script  which i will run in my server and get a list of the orphaned users,  with the list I've do some maintenance work, then i will do the clean up activity, and i dont have permission to access the Active directory or profile database

Comment: Why is the script not meeting your requirement? what is missing ?

Comment: Where does the file out file get saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the same code, I have commented the section to remove the user, once after testing, you can uncomment the section. **At line number 46, specify Your OUTPUT FILE NAME in which you will get all the Orphaned users in excel.**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
#Parameter 
$WebAppURL="YOUR WEB APPLICATION URL" 
#Function to Check if a User exists in AD 
Function Check-UserExistsInAD() 
{
    Param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$UserLoginID)
    Write-host $UserLoginID
    #Search the User in AD
    $Forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
    foreach ($Domain in $forest.Domains)
    {
        $context = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Domain", $Domain.Name)
        $domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($context)
        $root = $domain.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $search = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$root
        $search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$UserLoginID))"
        $result = $search.FindOne()
        if ($result -ne $null)
        {
        return $true
        }
        }
        return $false
    } 
    #Get all Site Collections of the web application 
    $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL 
    #Iterate through all Site Collections 
    Foreach($site in $WebApp.Sites) 
    {
        #Get all Webs with Unique Permissions - Which includes Root Webs
        $WebsColl = $site.AllWebs | Where {$_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True} | ForEach-Object {
        $OrphanedUsers = @()
        #Iterate through the users collection
        ForEach($User in $_.SiteUsers)
        {
            #Exclude Built-in User Accounts , Security Groups
            if(($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\authenticated users") -and($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "sharepoint\system") -and($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\local service") -and($user.IsDomainGroup -eq $false ) )
            {
                $UserName = $User.LoginName.split("\") 
                #Domain\UserName
                $AccountName = $UserName[1] #UserName
                if ( ( Check-UserExistsInAD $AccountName) -eq $false )
                {
                    Write-Host "$($User.Name)($($User.LoginName)) from $($_.URL)" #doesn't Exists in AD!"
                    $($User.Name);$($User.LoginName);$($_.URL) | out-file "d:OrphanedUsersRpt.txt" #Your OUTPUT FILE NAME
                    #Make a note of the Orphaned user
                    $OrphanedUsers+=$User.LoginName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
# **** Remove Users ****# 
# Remove the Orphaned Users from the site 
# foreach($OrpUser in $OrphanedUsers) 
# { 
# $_.SiteUsers.Remove($OrpUser) 
# Write-host "Removed the Orphaned user $($OrpUser) from $($_.URL) " 
# }
```

For more information, kindly check the below links,

1. https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/find-and-delete-orphaned-users-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html
2. https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/09/find-and-delete-orphaned-users-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: thanks for sharing this code, when i run this code and the other code which i mentioned , that is keep on running for a long time and displaying all the user name and its has duplicated values also

Comment: Obviously it will run for long time because it running for all the site collections in the web applications. Once you get the data in excel, you can remove the duplicate entries. You get the duplicate user values, because he might have access to site, list, files, etc. from every where it takes the user data and fills the excel/text output file

Comment: Okay, will do that, also, in the above code,  the output files has only one line of date of one user, is there anything else i need to do in the code other than changing the file name

Comment: updated the code and on 3rd line, specify the $WebAppURL="YOUR WEB APPLICATION URL"

Comment: Did this work ?

Comment: No Karthik, the output file has only the last username, i did manual copy paste and created the report, thank you so much for your help.